# How to remove rows from dataframe without rewriting it?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df = structure(list(V1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7), V2 = c(3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4), V3 = c(6.5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
trash = c(2,3)
```

How to remove the rows having the IDs in trash without rewriting the df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there are inplace operations in r, even if you do

```
df = structure(list(V1 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7), V2 = c(3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4), V3 = c(6.5, 8, 9, 5, 7, 4, 3, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
trash = c(2,3)
df = df[-trash,]
```

It should still rewrite df.